# deleted storyboard xcode but present during execution

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I deleted my storyboard by accident in XCode. However, when I run my app, the app executes as if the old storyboard is still present. Is there a way to get the old one back or have a new one take its place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you delete references so it may be available into the folder so open project folder and watch is there?if yes then add into project using drag and add reference into project

Comment: XCode offers you (every time you create a new project) if you'd like to create a local git repository for your project. It is recommended :-)

Comment: I have definitely learned my lesson and am starting to fall in love with git.

Comment: for people who are wondering why we can execute the app without storyboard file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22472194/938380

Answer (score 4):

### How to *probably* get the old one back

You have most likely just deleted the reference from your project so the file is still there. You can find the file by going to your project folder (on disk). It can be found by right clicking your project in Xcode and choosing "Show in Finder"

[image: Show in finder]

The Storyboard file should be located in your main locale folder (english per default)

[image: e.lproj]

If the file is there you can just drag it back to your project.

[image: Stoyboard file]

If it is not there you have to find the file some other way... You are using some kind of version control, right? You can also replace it with another storyboard.

### How to replace it with a new one

You can specify a new storyboard in the Summary tab of your target.

You can find it by

1. Pressing your project
2. Pressing your target
3. Selecting your new Storyboard from the drop down.

[image: Changing to another Storyboard]

Comment: Does this answer the question? Is this a way to recover from "deleting" a storyboard?

Comment: And, btw, that's all-honesty... I know Xcode deals almost exclusively with references and not hard file representations.

Comment: @ctrahey It answers the second part of the question "... or have a new one take its place?"

Comment: @ctrahey You are probably correct, it is most likely a file reference problem. I added a section to my answer on how to find and re-add the reference to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you run on simulator (and it has the version of storyboard you need), you probably can just get the storyboard from simulator app folder. In my case the path would be: 
 *~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/87519545-64CB-4917-B3CF-821F7BF968BD/audio converting.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc*

But it's always better to use e.g. git for source code versioning.

Hope it helps.