# Storyboard doesn't apply changes after using Base Internationalization

Tags: xcode, storyboard, radix

I'm localizing my app. I have already accomplished Use Base Internationalization and added 1  set language of files: `MainStoryboard.strings` (French) & `InfoPlist.strings` (French) which works fine.

My problem is that any changes I now make to the MainStoryboard.storyboard (like changing a label field font color) do not reflect the change when I run the app.

What am I doing wrong? Can you not change the storyboard attributes once you have done the use base internationalization?

Comment: @MiQUEL, I am late, but I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will compile your storyboard to something like `MainStoryboard.storyboardc` and store the `storyboardc` file in

```
<Your app folder>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<Your app name>.app/Base.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc
```

I believe there is a bug in the mechanism of `Base Internationalization`, which makes Xcode just use the old `storyboardc` rather than compile a new one. Thus, your changes to storyboard will not appear after using `Base Internationalization`.

To solve it, just remove the `Build` folder.

```
 rm -rf Build/
```

Xcode will compile storyboard again after deleting the folder.

If it still doesn't work, you may need to reset your simulator.