# Base Internationalization doesn't work for new storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode5

I was using Base Internationalization to localize my app. it was fine.

I added a new storyboard to my project (so I have 2 storybaords). I clicked the "localize" button on the Xcode right panel to apply Base Internationalization to my new storyboard.

I got `SecondStoryboard.strings` as expected, but the app didn't take the translated strings. The app still showed the language in storyboard, just like I didn't localize it. Internationalization still works for my first storyboard though.

There is not any error or waning, so it's super difficult to trace the problem.

I guess this is a Xcode bug that appears after upgrading from Xcode 4 to 5.

I know I can use `NSLocalizedString` to bypass this problem, but I think using  Base Internationalization for static string is the more elegant way to localize.
How can I make Base Internationalization normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the question is Xcode would not compile storyboard and keep using the old version of storyboard after localizing the file. I believe it's a bug from Apple.

short answer:

remove the `Build` folder in your app folder.

```
rm -rf Build/
```

and reset your simulator.

detailed answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22472194/938380